# getting value from an object in jstl, getting property name from a list

Tags: arrays, list, jstl, field, jstl-functions

I am new to [JSTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages_Standard_Tag_Library), I understand that to get field value we can use the following code:

```
<c:out value="${empDetails.id}" />
<c:out value="${empDetails.name}" />
<c:out value="${empDetails.dept}" />
<c:out value="${empDetails.locn}" />
```

I have a requirement to get the list of property names to be shown in UI in an arrayList, in JSP I want to iterate and get the value from empDetails.

I want to write something like below:

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
    <c:out value="${empDetails}" property="${item}/>
</c:forEach>
```

The List will contain values "id","name", "locan", "dept" etc.

Could some one please help how to do it?

Comment: Thanks for reply,  object name is empDetails, fields what I want to print is in the list. I want to pass the field name as string. It is similar to how we use reflection in java.  In your suggestion "id" is field name which I need to hard code in jsp. But I am getting this dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

I found answer in one of the stackoverflow questions,

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
    <c:out value="${empDetails[item]}" />
</c:forEach>
```